# EF Core One to One or Zero Relationship

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have Person and Address. Address is optional.
Please see below code

```cs
class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }

}

class Address
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Registration code is below:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Address>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(z => z.PersonID);
                entity.HasOne(p => p.Person)
                     .WithOne(a => a.Address)
                     .HasForeignKey<Person>(a => a.PersonID);
            });
```

How should i change mapping to make Address optionable?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Here

```
.HasForeignKey<Person>(a => a.PersonID)
```

you are telling EF that `Person.PersonID` will be a FK (foreign key) to `Address`, i.e. `Person` is dependent and is referencing the principal `Address`.

It should be other way around:

```
.HasForeignKey<Address>(a => a.PersonID)
```

This way, `Person` (the principal) will have 0..1 `Address`, and `Address` (the dependent) will have 1 `Person` (because the `PersonId` is both PK and FK).

This is called *Shared Primary Key association* and is the standard (and default) way of modelling *one to zero or one* relationship in EF Core.

For more info, see [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you clarify, in addition the OP would also need to specify `public Person Person { get; set; }` on `class Address` as well correct?  - Otherwise would be unable to specify specifically `entity.HasOne(p => p.Person)`

Comment: @ttugates Nope, neither navigation property is mandatory. If `Address` doesn't have `Person` navigation property, the fluent call will be `entity.HasOne<Person>()`

Comment: I'm a little confused by the answer.  It would seem that this would be 1..1 relationship as opposed to a 1..0,1.  What makes it "optionable"?

Comment: @JasonDWilson "optionable" is the dependent, i.e. person w/o address. in general it depends on which side of the relationship you are looking at. from person it is 1 to 0..1 address. from address it is 1..1 (address requires person)

Comment: also Address.PersonID is a foreign key. No need entity.HasKey(z => z.PersonID);