# How can I configure a one to one relationship to have the foreign key also be a primary key?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am trying to model a relationship like this:

```
public class MyContainer {
   
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class MyCompontentOne
{
    public MyContainer MyContainer {get;set;}

    public string Prop1{get;set;}
}
```

I'd like to configure it to get a table like this:

```
MyContainerId (FK & PK) | Prop1 |... other props
```

I've tried a lot of things using the Fluent API but I always get some errors no matter what I do. This is the latest I've tried: (adding a shadow property and make it the foreign key)

```
            mb.Entity<MyCompontentOne>().Property<int>("MyContainerId").IsRequired();
            
            mb.Entity<MyCompontentOne>().Property(o => o.Prop1).IsRequired();
            mb.Entity<MyCompontentOne>()
                .HasOne(o => o.MyContainer)
                .WithOne();
            
            mb.Entity<MyCompontentOne>().HasKey("MyContainerId");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF Core One to One or Zero Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54985032/ef-core-one-to-one-or-zero-relationship)

Comment: Hmm, you've updated the question while I was writing the answer. What's the problem with your latest update, basically it does the same as in my answer (just with a more explicit property mapping)? I've tested my answer before posting it and got the desired database model with no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my answer to the suggested duplicate question [EF Core One to One or Zero Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54985032/ef-core-one-to-one-or-zero-relationship), shared PK association (dependent entity with PK being also a FK) is the default EF Core mapping of one to one or zero required relationship.

What is specific in your question though (and prevents applying directly the answer to the related post) is the lack of explicit property in the dependent entity to be mapped as PK/FK. So what you are asking is possible, but requires dealing with [shadow properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties).

The following is the minimal fluent configuration which will configure one to one or zero relationship between `MyContainer` (principal) and `MyCompontentOne` (dependent) with (1) navigation property `MyContainer` in `MyCompontentOne`, (2) no navigation property in `MyContainer`, and (3) required shadow FK property (and column) `MyContainerId` in `MyCompontentOne`. Then (4) will map the shadow property as a PK:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<MyCompontentOne>()
    .HasOne(e => e.MyContainer) // (1)
    .WithOne() // (2)
    .HasForeignKey<MyCompontentOne>("MyContainerId") // (3)
    .IsRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<MyCompontentOne>()
    .HasKey("MyContainerId"); // (4)
```