# ef core multiple 1 to 1 or zero same class

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

trying to implement two instances of a  1 to 1 or 1 to zero navigation property in ef core using either data annotations or fluent api.

formation table is just id and name.

```
public class Formation {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

the well class can have but does not need to have a deepestformation of type formation
the well class can have but does not need to have a producingformation of type formation

```
public class Well
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }
    
            public long? DeepestFormationId { get; set; }
            public Formation DeepestFormation { get; set; }
    
            public long? ProducingFormationId { get; set; }
            public Formation ProducingFormation { get; set; }
        }
```

I am struggling how to set this up using either data annotations or the fluid api

I attempted

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Well>()
                 .HasOne(c => c.DeepestFormation)
                 .WithOne()
                 .HasForeignKey<Formation>(c => c.Id);
```

but where do I tell it that the foreign key is DeepestFormationId?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF Core One to One or Zero Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54985032/ef-core-one-to-one-or-zero-relationship)

Comment: Your foreign key is `DeepestFormationId`, `Formation.Id` is principial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I'd recommend you read ef core [Definition of terms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#definition-of-terms).

> Principal key: The properties that uniquely identify the principal entity. This may be the primary key or an alternate key.
>
> Foreign key: The properties in the dependent entity that are used to store the principal key values for the related entity.

Then you can try to change your mapping:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Well>()
             .HasOne(c => c.DeepestFormation)
             .WithOne()
             .HasForeignKey<Well>(c => c.DeepestFormationId);

  modelBuilder.Entity<Well>()
             .HasOne(c => c.ProducingFormation)
             .WithOne()
             .HasForeignKey<Well>(c => c.ProducingFormationId);
```

You optionally can specify the principle key - `.HasPrincipalKey(item => item.Id)`, but Ef core smart enough to resolve it.
Then you need to consider [`OnDelete` behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.deletebehavior?view=efcore-3.1). Be careful with it, if you set `Cascade`, in your case you might get [Multiple cascade path exception](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/5871)

Comment: that throws the error that formation does not have producingformationid I'm not sure