# Zero-or-one relationship in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have a somewhat special scenario of a Zero-or-one relationship in EF Core which cannot be easily modeled by the default (as described, e.g.,in [EF Core One to One or Zero Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54985032/ef-core-one-to-one-or-zero-relationship)).

I've got multiple entities with a 0-1 relationship to a "Match" entity. Multiple instances can reference the same "Match" entity (which is why I can't put the foreign key into the "Match" table, which seems to be the recommended way of modeling a 0-1 relationship).

How to define the relationship from one of the entities to 0-1 "Match" entities? Do I have to create a Match().HasMany(someKindOfBaseClassOfEntities) instead? Is there a better way?

Comment: You can't configure a navigation from Match to the match "owners", but you can configure each owner to have one `Match`, by `HasOne`.

Comment: But "HasOne", at least as far as I know, will create a non-optional 1:1 relationship. I also have "owners" without a corresponding "Match", so I need a 1:0-1 relationship.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure this by using `HasOne`, which allows a 1:0..1 relationship. Just showing one way of doing this without repeating too much mapping code:

Classes:

```cs
class Match
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

abstract class HasMatchBase
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? MatchID { get; set; }
    public Match Match { get; set; }
}

class A : HasMatchBase
{
    public string Code { get; set; } // Just an example
}

class B : HasMatchBase { }
```

Mapping configuration:

```cs
abstract class HasMatchBaseConfig<T> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>
    where T : HasMatchBase
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(b => b.Name).HasMaxLength(200);
        builder.HasOne(b => b.Match).WithOne().HasForeignKey<T>(b => b.MatchID);

        ConfigureMatchOwner(builder);
    }
    
    public abstract void ConfigureMatchOwner(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder);
}

class AConfig : HasMatchBaseConfig<A> 
{ 
    public override void ConfigureMatchOwner(EntityTypeBuilder<A> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(a => a.Code).HasColumnType("CHAR").HasMaxLength(3);
        ... // Further A-specific mapping
    }
}

class BConfig : HasMatchBaseConfig<B>
{
    public override void ConfigureMatchOwner(EntityTypeBuilder<B> builder)
    {
        ... // B-specific mapping. 
    }
}
```

The type of `HasMatchBase.MatchID` determines whether the association is required or optional. In this case it's a nullable `int`, turning the association into `Match` being optional.